# Как проверить через wireshark что выдает программа по udp

Tags: java, udp, wireshark

Приложение на Java осуществляет передачу данных по протоколу UDP в режиме Multicast

Вот код отправки данных:

```
private final static String IP_ADDR = "224.1.1.201";
DatagramSocket socket;
public void sending() {
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
    group = InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDR);
    sendingDataBuffer = parserData(dataBuffer);
    DatagramPacket packet 
    = new DatagramPacket(sendingDataBuffer, sendingDataBuffer.length, group, SERVICE_PORT);
    socket.send(packet);
}
```

Пытаюсь проверить с помощью программы wireshark что уходит в сеть.
Запустил wireshark, добавил фильтр

```
udp.port in {51491}
```

И wireshark ни чего не показывает на этом порту. Не пойму почему? Я с этой программой первый раз, может я не тот фильтр использую или не туда смотрю?

Comment: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/18459/udp-port-5353-filter/

Comment: Исправил фильтр на
"udp.port == 51491"
все равно на этом порту тишина

Comment: Значит тишина... Можно не спрашивать, что у Вас в константе SERVICE_PORT правильный порт, так ведь?

Comment: Да, причем я проверил, что этот порт свободен утилитой netstat -nao

Comment: Попробуйте проверить Wireshark любую другую активность на заранее известном порту для того, чтоб удостовериться в корректной работе/настройках/выполняемых Вами действиях Wireshark.

Comment: Проблема оказалась в том, что передающая сторона отправляла пакеты в сеть virtualBox, поэтому я их и не видел в Wireshark. С приемной стороной та же беда была, она тоже читала из сети virtualBox. Вот как мен в Java указать в какую сеть слать пакеты? Или это тема нового вопроса?

Comment: Да, это конечно новый вопрос, но могу Вам посоветовать перед тем, как задать вопрос уделить немного времени для поиска соответствующей информации в интернете. Например, вот первая ссылка по запросу: https://serverfault.com/a/333584